# Are Democrats alleging that Russia tampered with the vote tallies?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, democratic-party

In [Belief in conspiracies largely depends on political identity](https://today.yougov.com/news/2016/12/27/belief-conspiracies-largely-depends-political-iden/), it's reported that many democrats reported positively to a question about whether Russia tampered with the vote tallies for the 2016 presidential election:

> Half of Clinton’s voters think Russia even hacked the Election Day
>   votes (only 9% of Trump voters give that any credibility at all).

As far as I know, Democrats aren't actually alleging that the vote tallies are hacked. Instead, they allege that Russia encouraged people to vote Trump, including by hacking Democrat emails. Are Democrats actually promoting the claim that vote tallies were hacked?

Comment: IDK what you are looking for in an answer, but the question that the poll apparently asked has some problems with it. For example, it asks for a true or false answer to a question that hasn't really been studied. What if one thought it was possible, but didn't know? What would they answer? One might also consider Russia's actions an indirect way of tampering with vote tallies, by engineering people's thoughts (a significantly more-effective way to go about it in reality).

Comment: It sounds to me like he's asking if any moderately high-ranking Democratic party official has publicly alleged that Russia has tampered with the vote tallies.  It seems to be an answerable question.

Comment: Belief in conspiracies mostly correlates with specific psychological and cognitive profiles. There was a nice "You're not so smart" podcast episode about that research recently.

Comment: I don't know of any promotion of that idea. Regardless, that article is terrible. I don't think it actually comes to the same conclusion as its title. The title should be "belief in *specific* conspiracy theories can depend on political identity which is kind of like saying "NFL team affiliation is highly dependent on where people live". (ie, no duh.)

Comment: *Are Democrats actually promoting the claim that vote tallies were hacked?* Are there people who affiliate themselves with the democrat party claiming this? Yes.  I do not know of any leaders that actually believe this but that is what they seem to be trying to infer to their unwashed masses.

Comment: Re *'Belief in conspiracies largely depends on political identity'*: perhaps this present seeming inflexibility, is less of a historic generality, and more of a topical or contemporary side-effect of [the growing media monopolies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_of_media_ownership) of the last few decades, along with the [online media's "echo chamber" effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_chamber_%28media%29).

Comment: Frankly the public's confusion could be somewhat pardoned. I mean, read [Oct 23, 2020 news](https://apnews.com/article/donald-trump-iran-media-social-media-elections-8cccec2bd393098f9fb39b955ae52bde) "U.S. officials said Thursday that Russian hackers have targeted the networks of dozens of state and local governments in the United States in recent days, stealing data from at least two servers. The warning, less than two weeks before the election, amplified fears of the potential for tampering with the vote and undermining confidence in the results."

Comment: In contrast, in 2020 we have claims from Trump's legal team that Venezuela did that by <s>hacking</s> *creating* the voting machines' software. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/49884/was-any-part-of-the-technology-used-in-americas-2020-election-created-by-venezu